# How to fool Kerio filtering rule?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, mime-types

There are a filtering rule in our office that prevent clients from downloading audio and video files. This rule is set using a Kerio server.

For example when I enter a direct link to a `.mp4` file, I face this page from this Kerio firewall:

[image]

Well, to bypass this filtering rule, I wrote a python program using flask on a web-server to receive the address of that file as an argument in address bar, download it on that server, change its extension to a non-audio/non-video extension (for example `.fk`, `.pdf` and so on) and then send it to me!

Here is the program:

`__init__.py:`

```
# encoding=utf8
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
import Downup

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

downupper = Downup.Downup()

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def test_1(path):
    url = "http://"+ path[6:]
    file_addr = downupper.downup(url)
    return send_file(file_addr, mimetype=None, as_attachment=False, attachment_filename=None, add_etags=True, cache_timeout=None, conditional=False)
    #return file_addr

@app.route('/test_2')
def test_2():
    return '<html><body><h1>Hi!</h1></body></html>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

*Downup.py*

```
import os
import urllib
import random

class Downup():
    def __init__(self):
        self.download_path = "/var/lib/openshift/55ed2d400c1e6677a50001d1/app-root/data/"

    def downup(self, url):
        file_downloader = urllib.URLopener()
        file_name = str(random.randint(1,99999999999)) + "-" + "change .fk to " + str(url)[-4:] +".fk"
        try:
            file_downloader.retrieve(url, self.download_path + file_name)
            return self.download_path + file_name
        except:
            return "Failed!"
```

The problem is I still face the previous filtering page:

[image]

As you see, I pass the address of file as an argument to my application (here: `fcuk-kerio.rhcloud.com`), it is downloaded on the server with a different extension and the sended with `none` as its *Mime*, but it still failed.

Note that I checked the host, and I see my file is downloaded there:

[image]

Here is the log:

[image]

*Note that I can bypass the Kerio server using VPNs and Proxy servers, but I want to do it using above methodology.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible for me to say for sure, since I don't have this product to test with.  There are two obvious problems.

First, the url still contains the extension.  Try posting the url you want to download from a form, rather than as a url argument.

Second, the mimetype is just a hint to the browser, changing it doesn't actually change the file.  Files have "magic numbers", unique headers that can reliably identify most file types without needing extension and mimetype hints.  You could try to base64 encode the file rather than sending it as a download, then decode it on your end.

Base64 encoding is a simple version of what you should really be doing: using secure HTTP (https, ssl, tls, etc.).  The reason that VPNs and proxies work for you is that they encrypt all the traffic between your machine and the outside, so that the firewall can't examine it.